# custom item writer to write to database using list of list which contains hashmap

Tags: spring-batch, spring-jdbc

i am a new to spring batch and my requirement is to read a dynamic excel sheet and insert into database.I am able to read excel and pass it to writer but only last record in excel sheet gets inserted into database. Here is my code for item writer

```
@Bean
public ItemWriter<List<LinkedHashMap<String, String>>> tempwrite() {

 JdbcBatchItemWriter<List<LinkedHashMap<String, String>>> databaseItemWriter = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<>();
    databaseItemWriter.setDataSource(dataSource);

    databaseItemWriter.setSql("insert into table values(next value for seq_table,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

    ItemPreparedStatementSetter<List<LinkedHashMap<String, String>>> valueSetter = 
            new databasePsSetter();



    databaseItemWriter.setItemPreparedStatementSetter(valueSetter);

    return databaseItemWriter;
}
```

and below is my prepared statement setter class

```
public class databasePsSetter implements ItemPreparedStatementSetter<List<LinkedHashMap<String, String>>> {

    @Override
    public void setValues(List<LinkedHashMap<String, String>> item, PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {


        int columnNumber=1;

        for(LinkedHashMap<String, String> row:item){
            columnNumber=1;
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : row.entrySet()) {

                ps.setString(columnNumber, entry.getValue());
                columnNumber++;

            }

        }


    }

}
```

I have seen many examples but all of them is using a dto class but i am not sure whether this is the correct way of implementation for list of list which contains hashmap

Comment: did u try to debug? put a breakpoint and see if you got to the writer for each line?

Comment: Yes I did and it looks like my prepared statement is getting overridden. I am not sure how to use addbatch here as when I did it said it can't use addbatch in prepared statement. Once my first set of prepared statements is set, it needs to be executed but I am missing how to do it

Comment: where is your 'jdbcTemplate'? do u have a NamedParameterJdbcTemplate ?

Comment: i do not have a namedparameterjdbctemplate. as my excel sheet is dynamic and it can refer to any table for import based on parameter.my input data is present in list of list of linked hashmaps .using which i need to iterate and make insert to database